# Using UIWebView to launch a video from an HTML a href link, but html does not appear when video is DONE

Tags: video, uiwebview

I want to be able to launch a video from an  link in html that I load into a UIWebView. The video launches just fine, but when either I hit the DONE button on the video player or when the video ends, it returns to the UIWebView, but the html that I had placed on the UIWebView is gone (including the a href link).

Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your UIWebView control is following your link, and navigating to a new page. As this page contains only a video (it's not an HTML page), the iPhone goes into full page view, and shows the video.  When you are done, you return to the last page, which happens to be the video.  If you had a way to invoke the "Back" action, you'd get to the page you want.

You should look into using the HTML <video> tag to embed your video.  That will show an of your video (check out the "poster" attribute).  When you click on this, it will launch the video in full screen mode and when it is done, you'll end up on the same page you started.

If you want to launch the video from a textual link, you can do something like this:

```
<video id="video" src="LINK TO YOUR VIDEO" height="40" width="40" poster="Icon-Small.png"></video>
<p onclick="javascript:startVideo()">Watch the intro video.</p>
```

... and include a script along these lines:

```
var startVideo = function()
{
    var video = document.getElementById("video"); 
    video.play();
}
```

... and style the text to look like a link, etc.